# Deploying linux CUDA app

Tags: deployment, cuda, nvidia

I've compiled a cu program on my laptop, using NVIDIA CUDA 5 toolkit. A very basic interface, using only terminal output. Then I went on to test how it runs on my desktop PC (both have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed).

On the desktop PC I get this error message:

error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Ok, I get it, some libs are not installed. But do I really need to install CUDA toolkit on every PC where I'd want my compiled code to run?

Comment: You don't have to install the complete toolkit, but at least you have to install the required libraries. If you only use "standard" methods like cudamemcpy, cudamalloc.. than cudart should be enough.

Answer (score 8):

To deploy a CUDA runtime API application on linux you only need to do two things:

1. Make sure that the machine in question has a CUDA compatible card and a minimum driver version which matches the CUDA Toolkit you used to build the application (you can find information regarding both of these in the release notes of the toolkit)
2. Distribute the *runtime library* (so cudart.so) that you built the application against with the executable. If you used any other libraries from the toolkit (like CUBLAS, CUFFT, CUSPARSE, etc) you need to inlcude those too. The CUDA runtime library is versioned and you have to have the libraries which match the toolkit you are building with. You may need to use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to ensure that the correct versions of the libraries are found by the link loader. Often a simple shell script which acts the canonical application, settings `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable and running the built executable is the best way to do this.

If you get those two things right, it should just work.